# Server side validation for reCAPTCHA V2 or Invisible reCAPTCHA with Java (Servlet)

Tags: java, validation, servlets, captcha

The main reason for this post is that I spent quite a lot of time searching the easiest way to validate recaptcha V2. So I'm going to share my knowledge to avoid further time wastage of developers.

I'm using `org.json` library for this. Get the .jar file from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar) or read the [docs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107). Add the .jar. file to your project and import the following classes.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Use the following method to for validation:

```
/**
 * Validates Google reCAPTCHA V2 or Invisible reCAPTCHA.
 * @param secretKey Secret key (key given for communication between your site and Google)
 * @param response reCAPTCHA response from client side. (g-recaptcha-response)
 * @return true if validation successful, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isCaptchaValid(String secretKey, String response) {
    try {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?"
                + "secret=" + secretKey
                + "&response=" + response;
        InputStream res = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        String jsonText = sb.toString();
        res.close();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json.getBoolean("success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call the above method as shown:

```
if(isCaptchaValid("enter_your_key_here", request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response"))){
    //valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One small criticism of you're code that I'll offer is that the loop in the middle which reads a stream could be usefully factored out and put in a general utility.  Reading a stream is a common problem and could be made more general.

In fact I have a small routine to do that sitting here on my hard drive.  Here's my version:

```
public class IoUtils
{

   private IoUtils() {}

   public static CharSequence readFully( Reader reader )
           throws IOException
   {
      char[] buffer = new char[ 1024 ];
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      for( int length; ( length = reader.read( buffer ) ) != -1; )
         stringBuilder.append( buffer, 0, length );
      return stringBuilder;
   }

   public static ByteArrayOutputStream readFully( InputStream ins )
           throws IOException
   {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] bytes = new byte[ 1024 ];
      for( int length; ( length = ins.read( bytes ) ) != -1; )
         bos.write( bytes, 0, length );
      return bos;
   }
}
```

Use it something like this:

```
    InputStream res = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    CharSequence cs = IoUtils.readFully( rd );

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject( cs.toString() );
```

Reading a stream as UTF-8 is so common you might even want to make a separate method just for that.  Then you could do

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject( IoUtils.readFullyUtf8( 
         new URL(url).openStream() ).toString() );
```

Some might find a single line of code more clear to read.